# Solve is taking much longer time to compute

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[a*Subscript[x, 2] == 
   0 && -a*Subscript[x, 1] + 
    b*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 3]]*Subscript[x, 3] - 
    h*Subscript[x, 2] == 
  0 && -c*Subscript[x, 3] - I*b*Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[x, 1] + e -
     I*g*Subscript[x, 5] == 
   0 && -f*Subscript[x, 4] - f - 
    2*I*g*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 5]]*Subscript[x, 3] + 
    2*I*g*Subscript[x, 5]*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 3]] == 
   0 && -(f/2 + I*d)*Subscript[x, 5] + 
    I*g*Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[x, 3] == 0, {Subscript[x, 1], 
  Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}]
```

is the expression which I am trying to compute but it is taking too much time. it is been 5 days the code is running but no output yet.

Comment: You are solving for x_1 to x_5. But what about the  variables (?) a,b, h... and so on. Can you provide the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

These are strange equations, e.g. $a \cdot x_2 =0$ means that $x_2=0$ if it should be valid for all $a$.

Set

```
equ=a*Subscript[x, 2] == 
       0 && -a*Subscript[x, 1] + 
        b*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 3]]*Subscript[x, 3] - 
        h*Subscript[x, 2] == 
       0 && -c*Subscript[x, 3] - I*b*Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[x, 1] + e -
         I*g*Subscript[x, 5] == 
       0 && -f*Subscript[x, 4] - f - 
        2*I*g*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 5]]*Subscript[x, 3] + 
        2*I*g*Subscript[x, 5]*Conjugate[Subscript[x, 3]] == 
       0 && -(f/2 + I*d)*Subscript[x, 5] + 
        I*g*Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[x, 3] == 0
```

This works fine:

```
   Solve[equ, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4],Subscript[x, 5]}]
```

or you leave some variables open:

```
Solve[equ, {a, b, c, d, Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x,3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}]
```

> {{a -> 0,    c -> (e - I b Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] - 
>       I g Subscript[x, 5])/Subscript[x, 3],    d -> (-2 g Subscript[x, 
>        3] (f + 2 I g Conjugate[Subscript[x, 5]] Subscript[x, 3]) + 
>       I (f^2 + 4 g^2 Abs[Subscript[x, 3]]^2) Subscript[x, 5])/(    2 f Subscript[x, 5]),    Subscript[x, 2] -> (b Abs[Subscript[x, 3]]^2)/h, 
>   Subscript[x,     4] -> -((
>       f + 2 I g (Conjugate[Subscript[x, 5]] Subscript[x, 3] - 
>           Conjugate[Subscript[x, 3]] Subscript[x, 5]))/f)}}